# Transfer CSV files from iPhone to MacBook

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, data-transfer

My application creates CSV files, stored in the documents directory, with the purpose of being later imported into Microsoft Excel.  What is the best way to transfer these files in an end-user-friendly way, via the iPhone USB cable, to a MacBook?  If there is some way to do this exclusively with code on the phone itself (doubtful) that would be ideal.  However, I would be amendable to writing a cocoa application for this purpose.

iPhone 3G 3.1.3
MacBook Pro 10.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferring files via USB is not officially supported on the iPhone platform and Apple probably won't approve your App if you'd use it:
http://techcrunch.com/2010/02/02/apple-stanza-usb/

For now, you should send the files as emails and hope for some kind of file storage support in the next version of iPhone OS.

Comment: What is the de facto method for uploading files at this point?  Do many people just host a server?  I've in the past used the GameKit for iPhone-iPhone bluetooth transfer, but is iPhone-MacBook bluetooth transfer supported, if not with this framework than with another similar, condoned one?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but standard bluetooth file transfer protocols aren't available either.
Most iPhone apps I've seen offer to send files via email. Others start a local http server and let the user connect via wifi. And some are already backed by a webapp and upload to there.

Comment: Ugh.  Okay.  Thanks.  Hopefully they will include file transfer soon.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this right now. Most applications wind up using WiFi along with some other protocol like WebDav, HTTP POST, AFP, or proprietary ones with a custom app on the Mac.